# passing an array of structs to a function and changing it through the fucntion

Tags: c++, c, arrays, function, struct

so this is my code but it wont compile for some reason.

Error   3   error C2036: 'pjs *' : unknown size 
Error   4   error C2100: illegal indirection
Error   5   error C2037: left of 'size' specifies undefined struct/union 'pjs'

```
void initArray(struct pjs* array)
{

    (*array[1]).size = 1;
}
struct pjs{
 char* name;
 int size;
 int price;
};
int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
    struct pjs array[10];
    initArray(array);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: in C, object definitions must be known before being used.  suggest placing the struct definition before where it is first used, rather than after where it is first used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help:

```
struct pjs{
    char* name;
    int size;
    int price;
};

// safer to use one of the following declaration
// void initArray(pjs *array, std::size_t size) // simpler
// void initArray(pjs (&array)[10]) // more restrictive but unintuitive syntax
void initArray(pjs* array)
{
    array[1].size = 1;
}

int main()
{
    pjs array[10];
    initArray(array);
}
```

- Definition of `pjs` should be given before to use it (or requiring its size).
- `array[1]` is a `pjs` so `*array[1]` is illegal (as `pjs` no have `operator*`)

Comment: Having the declaration/type definition _before_ its usage is actually required, not just recommended as "should" implies.

Comment: ty very much this was the problem!! @Jarod42

Answer (score 1):

That simply should be

```
array[1].size = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your 1st statement of initArray to :

```
array[1].size = 1;
```

and cut paste the struct declaration to before the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize the entire array, you need to pass the array and a size to `initArray`.

```
int main(int argc , char** argv)
{
    struct pjs array[10];
    initArray(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]));
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
```

and then, initialize each object the array as:

```
void initArray(struct pjs* array, size_t size)
{
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
   {
      array[i].size = 1;
      array[i].price = 0; // Or whatever makes sense
      array[i].name = malloc(1); // Or whatever makes sense. 
   }
}
```